# Game of Life: Tried to increase computation efficiency with new algorithm, reduced in stead. Why?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, conways-game-of-life

I'm programming Conway's Game of Life and have produced a working, smooth JS program. What I do in the working version is to check each neighboring coordinate of every coordinate in the grid, and either kill or spawn it based on its number of neighbors. Now I want to make the algorithm more efficient by keeping track of which coordinates are alive, and only process those and their neighbors, instead of the whole grid. I made this alternative program:

```
var g = 0;
var cellMatrix = new Array();
var height = 68;  
var width = 100;
var livingCellIndex = 0;
var livingCells = new Array();

writeBoard();
declareFirstGeneration();
live();

function live() {

    processGeneration();
    g++;
    setTimeout(live, speed);

}

function declareNextGeneration() {

    livingCells[g + 1] = new Array();

    cellMatrix[g + 1] = new Array();

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {

        cellMatrix[g + 1][x] = new Array();

        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {

            cellMatrix[g + 1][x][y] = false;
        }
    }
}

function declareFirstGeneration() {

    livingCells[g] = new Array();

    cellMatrix[g] = new Array();

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {

        cellMatrix[g][x] = new Array();

        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {

            cellMatrix[g][x][y] = false;
        }
    }
}

function processGeneration() {

    declareNextGeneration();

    livingCellIndex = 0;

    var x, y;

    for (var i = 0; i < livingCells[g].length; i++) {

        x = livingCells[g][i][0];
        y = livingCells[g][i][1];

        numberOfNeighbors = getLivingNeighbors(x, y);
        //console.log("numberOfNeighbors", numberOfNeighbors);
        if (numberOfNeighbors == 2 || numberOfNeighbors == 3) {
            spawnCell(g + 1, x, y);
        } else {
            killCell(g + 1, x, y);
        }

        for (var neighborX = x - 1; neighborX <= x + 1; neighborX++) {
            for (var neighborY = y - 1; neighborY <= y + 1; neighborY++) {
                if (neighborX < width && neighborX >= 0 && neighborY < height && neighborY >= 0) {
                    numberOfNeighbors = getLivingNeighbors(neighborX, neighborY);
                    //console.log(g, neighborX, neighborY, "has ", numberOfNeighbors, " neighbors");
                    if (numberOfNeighbors == 3) {
                        spawnCell(g + 1, neighborX, neighborY);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    refreshGenerationDisplay(x,y);
}

function spawnCell(g, x, y) {

    cellMatrix[g][x][y] = true;
    livingCells[g][livingCellIndex] = new Array(2);
    livingCells[g][livingCellIndex][0] = x;
    livingCells[g][livingCellIndex][2] = y;
    document.getElementById(x + '-' + y).style.background = "green"; // visual grid 
    livingCellIndex++;
}


function killCell(g, x, y) {
    cellMatrix[g][x][y] = false;
    document.getElementById(x + '-' + y).style.background = "none"; // visual grid
}
```

But I find that it is a lot slower than my first program. It seems like the computational cost of calculating each generation seems to increase with each generation. This surprises me because I though less data is handled in this alternative algorithm. I'm not sure if it is of interest, but here is the first version:

```
var g = 0;
var cellMatrix = new Array();
var height = 68;  
var width = 100;

declareThisGeneration();

function live() {

    g++;

    processGeneration();
    setTimeout(live, speed);

}

function processGeneration() {

    if (oscillation) adjustGForOscillation();
    if (g > 0) {
        processNormalGeneration();
    } else {
        processFirstGeneration();
    }
}

function processFirstGeneration() {

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {                
        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            processFirstGenCell(g, x, y);
        }
    }
}

function processFirstGenCell(g, x, y) {

    if (cellMatrix[g][x][y]) { //if alive
        spawnCell(g, x, y);
    } else { //if dead
        killCell(g, x, y);
    }
}


function processNormalGeneration() {

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {                
        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            processCell(g, x, y);
        }
    } 
}

function processCell(g, x, y) {

    var livingNeighbors = getLivingNeighbors(g - 1, x, y);

    if (cellMatrix[g - 1][x][y]) { //if alive
        if (livingNeighbors != 2 && livingNeighbors != 3) {
            killCell(g, x, y);
        } else {
            spawnCell(g, x, y);
        }
    } else { //if dead
        if (livingNeighbors == 3) {
            spawnCell(g, x, y);
        } else {
            killCell(g, x, y);
        }
    }
}

function spawnCell(g, x, y) {
    cellMatrix[g][x][y] = true;
    document.getElementById(x + '-' + y).className = 'alive';
}

function killCell(g, x, y) {

    cellMatrix[g][x][y] = false;
    document.getElementById(x + '-' + y).className = ''
}
```

My question is, what makes the "improved" algorithm so slow, and how can I reduce its cost?

[Version 1](http://tunetiles.com) // first, fastest

[Version 2](http://tunetiles.com/test.php) // new, slower

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you just showed the parts that have changed from the first to the second version. And maybe post the full code(s) in a fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You keep allocating new Arrays for each generation in the new version; in the old version, you keep re-using the same grid.  In addition to being slower, if not a REASON for it being slower, is that your memory footprint keeps growing.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that if you keep track on too many things, the computer will need to allocate more memory to store them, and that takes time.